# How to use a library in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am learning typescript.
Faced the problem of connecting the axios library.

File main.ts

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/axios/index.d.ts" />
//import axios from 'axios';

export function ok_lets_go()
{
  axios.get('https://ya.ru')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.status);
  });
}
```

If I uncomment the import line in the code

```
//import axios from 'axios';
```

Then everything compiles fine with no errors. But then this very import line gets into the Js code, and the browser swears at it (Edge based on Chromium).

If I use the line

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/axios/index.d.ts" />
```

then compilation errors occur

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'axios'.

error TS7006: Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

File **axios/index.d.ts** exists, try to set the name wrong - there is an error message that the file is not found.

File index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>eXtodo</title>
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; Charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./build/axios.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='app'></div>

    <script type="module">
      import {ok_lets_go} from './build/main.js';
      ok_lets_go();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

File tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["./src"],
}
```

Comment: `then((response: {data:any, status: any}) => ` will solve the second error

Comment: The first one appeared because you are missing the import for axios

Comment: The first one ‘import axios from “axios”’ is standard code.  I’m not sure what you are trying to do with referencepath

Comment: The problem is that if you use import, JS code is generated with this import line. And this import line throws an error in the browser.